# Using recursion to string format YAML file

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, yaml

I have a yaml file that I converted into a nested dictionary variable. The dictionary is passed into a python function (`render_yaml_dict()`) that takes the nested dictionary with unformatted values and returns the nested dictionary with formatted values. I'm using recursion to parse through the nested dictionary and jinja formatting to format string values with sibling values.

**Here's the function's input nested dictionary:**

```
{'y': {'a1': 'foo', 'a2': 'bar{{a1}}', 'a3': {'b1': 'bird', 'b2': 'red{{b1}}'}},
 'x': {'c1': 'turtle'}}
```

**Here's the function's expected returned value:**

```
{'y': {'a1': 'foo', 'a2': 'barfoo', 'a3': {'b1': 'bird', 'b2': 'redbird'}},
 'x': {'c1': 'turtle'}}
```

**Here's the function's actual returned value:**

```
{'y': {'a1': 'foo', 'a2': 'barfoo', 'a3': {'b1': 'bird', 'b2': 'red{{b1}}'}},
 'x': {'c1': 'turtle'}}
```

**Problem**

As you can see in the actual returned value above, the function does not format the `b2` value and outputs the original unformatted value of `'red{{b1}}'`. `a3` which is the immediate parent of `b2` is added to the `parent_list` (which is supposed to happen) although the problem is that `a3` is also added to the `visited` list without any explicit code to do so (see  ### PROBLEM:### within `render_yaml_dict()` function below). So when `render_yaml_dict()` checks to see if the parent_list is in the visited list, `'b2': 'red{{b1}}'` doesn't get passed into the jinja templating code. If you run the code block, the print statement that shows this issue is below.

```
 stack list
[[('a1', 'foo'), ('a2', 'bar{{a1}}'), ('a3', {'b1': 'bird', 'b2': 'red{{b1}}'})]]

immediate_parent
a3
visited BEFORE appending immediate parent to parent_list
[['x'], ['y']]
parent_list BEFORE appending immediate parent to parent_list
['y']
parent_list AFTER appending immediate parent to parent_list
['y', 'a3']
visited AFTER appending immediate parent to parent_list
[['x'], ['y', 'a3']]
```

**Here's the python function I have so far:**

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
from yaml import safe_load
from jinja2 import Template, Undefined

def get_by_path(root, items):
    """Access a nested object in root by item sequence."""
    return reduce(operator.getitem, items, root)

def set_by_path(root, items, value):
    """Set a value in a nested object in root by item sequence."""
    get_by_path(root, items[:-1])[items[-1]] = value

def render_yaml_dict(nested_dict):
    # used for jinja formatting 
    class NullUndefined(Undefined):
        def __getattr__(self, key):
            return ''
    stack = list(nested_dict.items()) 
    visited = []
    parent_list = []
    while stack: 
        #dict used to store non nested key : value pairs
        not_dict = {}
        #dict used to store key : nested value pairs
        is_dict = {}
        #reset is_stack to false for every stack iteration
        is_stack = False
        immediate_parent = None
        print('\n \n stack list')
        print(stack)
        #pop last value in stack list
        current_stack = stack.pop()
        #if the current_stack is a tuple, put in list before converting to dict
        if isinstance(current_stack, tuple):
            stack_dict = dict([current_stack])
        else:
            stack_dict = dict(current_stack)
        #ordered list of parent keys that are parents of nested values
        for key,value in stack_dict.items():   
            #if value is a nested dictionary and the list of upstream parents haven't been chronologically visited
            if isinstance(value, dict) and parent_list not in visited:
                immediate_parent = key
                add_to_stack = list(value.items())
                is_dict.update({key:value})
                is_stack = True
            #if value isn't a nested dictionary and the list of upstream parents haven't been chronologically visited
            elif isinstance(value, dict) == False and parent_list not in visited:
                not_dict.update({key:value})
            else:
                continue

        # if key value pairs exist in not_dict dictionary
        if not_dict:
            #create duplicate dictionary of values to use for templating
            t = Template(str(not_dict), undefined=NullUndefined)
            c = safe_load(t.render())
            #format dictionary of values with template dictionary
            formatted_dict = safe_load(t.render(c))
            # add is_dict to formatted_dict because set_by_path() updates inplace
            formatted_dict = {**formatted_dict, **is_dict}
            # update nested_dict with formatted_dict
            set_by_path(nested_dict, parent_list, formatted_dict)
            # if there is only one parent node
            if len(parent_list) == 1:
                #append parent_list to visited
                visited.append(parent_list)
            elif len(parent_list) > 1:
                #append parent_list by don't include immediate parent
                visited.append(parent_list[:-1])
            else:
                pass
        #if there is atleast one key:nested value pair in current_stack
        if is_stack == True:
            ### PROBLEM:### The immediate_parent is added to the visited list even though there's no code that explicitly does
            print('\nimmediate_parent')
            print(immediate_parent)
            print('visited BEFORE appending immediate parent to parent_list')
            print(visited)
            print('parent_list BEFORE appending immediate parent to parent_list')
            print(parent_list)
            #add latest parent to parent_list
            parent_list.append(immediate_parent)  
            print('parent_list AFTER appending immediate parent to parent_list')
            print(parent_list)
            print('visited AFTER appending immediate parent to parent_list')
            print(visited)
            #add latest key: nested value pair to stack
            if len(add_to_stack) > 1:
                stack.append(add_to_stack)
            else:
                stack.extend(add_to_stack)
        #if there are no key: nested value pairs in current_stack, reset parent_list 
        else:
            if len(parent_list) > 1:
                del parent_list[-1]
            else:
                parent_list = []

    return nested_dict
config = {'y': {'a1': 'foo', 'a2': 'bar{{a1}}', 'a3': {'b1': 'bird', 'b2': 'red{{b1}}'}},
 'x': {'c1': 'turtle'}}
render_yaml_dict(config)
```

Comment: Why don't you use a library like `pyyaml`?

Comment: @bigbounty I'm currently looking at the `pyyaml` docs. Does `pyyaml` have a method or a parameter you have to pass to format yaml values with sibling values?

Comment: Why not look into this library - https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-benedict?

Comment: @bigbounty what would be useful for this problem in python benedict?

Comment: There is nothing added to the visited list. It contained two elements before, and it contains two elements afterwards. The value of the second element simply changed since you modified it.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible because imports are missing and it references an unknown function `set_by_path`, please update it so that the problem is reproducible. Also, you don't show the actual output so it is unclear how the problem impacts what you want to do. Finally, what should be the result of loading `{'a': 'a{{b}}', 'b': 'b{{a}}'}`?

Comment: Anyway, you're converting dicts to a string representation with `str(…)`. This does not necessarily produce valid YAML and is likely to be the actual problem. And copying a dict by getting its string representation and parsing that again is madness; just use `not_dict.copy()` (or `copy.deepcopy(not_dict)` for deep copy).

Comment: @flyx Thank you for your great suggestions. I updated my post to reflect the needed changes.  As of your question regarding why I converted the dictionary to a string, the `Template` function from Jinja2 requires a string value. If there's a way to format jinja values within a nested dictionary without having to convert it to a string I would definitely prefer that. I agree as you said, converting a dict to a string and then parsing it again is madness but using `Template()` is my only workaround for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This endeavor seems to be far easier to implement by registering a custom constructor on YAML mappings:

```py
import yaml
from yaml.resolver import *
from jinja2 import Template, Undefined

class NullUndefined(Undefined):
   def __getattr__(self, key):
     return ''

source = '''
{'y': {'a1': 'foo', 'a2': 'bar{{a1}}', 'a3': {'b1': 'bird', 'b2': 'red{{b1}}'}},
 'x': {'c1': 'turtle'}}
'''

def resolve_in_dict(loader, node):
  assert isinstance(node, yaml.MappingNode)
  values = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
  for key, value in values.items():
    if isinstance(value, str):
      t = Template(value, undefined=NullUndefined)
      values[key] = t.render(values)
  return values

yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(BaseResolver.DEFAULT_MAPPING_TAG, resolve_in_dict)

print(yaml.safe_load(source))
```

This will execute `resolve_in_dict` on every mapping in your YAML file (that doesn't have an explicit tag other than `!!map`). It generates your expected output. If you reference dicts with a Jinja variable, they will of course be rendered as string because what else should happen with `a{{b}}` if `b` refers to a dict?

Comment: This is a far simpler implementation. Thank you very much @flyx